# TIME part of DateTime in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

In SQL Server I need to extract the time portion from this datetime `'2014-01-01 14:13:00.000'` in `'hh:mi:ss'` or `'hh:mi:ss:mmm'` format.

I have tried this query but the output is wrong, why?

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance

```
SELECT
    CONVERT (VARCHAR (12), '2014-01-01 14:13:00.000', 114) 'hh:mi:ss:mmm',
    CONVERT (VARCHAR (8), '2014-01-01 14:13:00.000', 108) 'hh:mi:ss';
```

Output:

```
'hh:mi:ss:mmm'  'hh:mi:ss'
2014-01-01 1    2014-01-
```

Comment: What **version** of SQL Server are you using? If you're on SQL Server **2008** or newer, use `CAST(your-datetime AS TIME(3))` and then display that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .NET FORMAT function is also available to SQL Server. You can use it as follows:

```
SELECT
    FORMAT( CONVERT(datetime,'2014-01-01T14:13:00.000'),
        'HH:mm:ss:fff' ) 'hh:mi:ss:mmm (custom)',
    FORMAT( CONVERT(datetime,'2014-01-01T14:13:00.000'),
        'HH:mm:ss' )    'hh:mi:ss (custom)',
    FORMAT( CONVERT(datetime,'2014-01-01T14:13:00.000'),
        'T', 'NL-nl' ) 'hh:mi:ss (standard)';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT cast(AttDate as time) [time]
```

Comment: Works on SQL Server **2008** or newer

Answer (score 1):

Your conversions *would* be correct if you were converting *from* datetime values:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT (
        VARCHAR (12),
        CONVERT(datetime,'2014-01-01T14:13:00.000'),
        114
    ) 'hh:mi:ss:mmm',
    CONVERT (
        VARCHAR (8),
        CONVERT(datetime,'2014-01-01T14:13:00.000'),
        108
    ) 'hh:mi:ss';
```

Result:

```
hh:mi:ss:mmm hh:mi:ss
------------ --------
14:13:00:000 14:13:00
```

As it is, your current code is asking to convert *from* char-style data *to* char-style data, and so the *style* parameter is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT RIGHT('2014-01-01 14:13:00.000', 12)
```

or

```
SELECT LEFT(RIGHT('2014-01-01 14:13:00.000', 12), 8)
```

If the date is in a table you can just put CONVERT(nvarchar, x) of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT CONVERT(TIME(0),'2014-01-01 14:13:00.000')  --> Will give 'hh:mi:ss'


SELECT CONVERT(TIME(3),'2014-01-01 14:13:00.000')  --> Will give 'hh:mi:ss:mmm'
```